# Navbar Bootstrap bug when change window size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

```css
body{
 font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
.navbar > .container-fluid{
 padding: 20px 40px;
}
.navbar-brand{
 margin-top: -8px;
}
.navbar-brand > small{
 font-weight: 100;
}
.navbar{
 background-color: transparent;
 border: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Portfolio</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#my-collapse-navbar" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Jos&eacute; Salazar<br></a>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="my-collapse-navbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact me</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

So I got a navbar with bootstrap which is working fine until I change the size of the window to see how it looks on mobile. It seems like hover and cursor:pointer from bootstrap stop working for a while. the same happens when I change the window to normal. any ideas how to fix this bug?

Comment: Did you already check the inspect element to see if all the files are taken in your website?

Comment: It seems that the problem is with chrome. I tested on safari and works fine. I also went to lyft.com and it has the same bug